# Unity Physics2D.Raycast hits itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, raycasting

I'm trying to use `Physics2D.Raycast` in order to check if the player is on the ground (I know that there are other approaches to check if the player is on the ground but I think that the raycast is the most reliable).
The problem is that in my scenario it returns the player itself as hit and I really don't understand why and what should I do.
My code (in `PlayerController`) is the following:

```
 public bool IsGrounded () {
        Bounds bounds = this.playerCollider.bounds;
        Vector3 rayOrigin = bounds.center;
        rayOrigin.y -= bounds.extents.y;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (rayOrigin, Vector2.down, 0.1f);
        if (hit.collider != null) {
            Debug.Log ("Collider is: " + hit.collider.name);
        }
        return hit.collider != null;
    }
```

And I can debug the casted ray using:

```
Debug.DrawLine (rayOrigin, new Vector3 (rayOrigin.x, rayOrigin.y - 0.1f, rayOrigin.z), Color.magenta);
```

...and it gets casted as expected, while the `Debug.Log` always reports "Player" which is itself and I don't know how it's possible. So what's wrong?

ps. I'm using Unity 5.3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is occurring because your Player is overlapping at the start of the raycast. There are few ways to fix this:

**1**.Disable **Queries Start In Colliders**.

Go to **Edit**->**Project Settings**->**Physics 2D** then make sure that **Queries Start In Colliders** is NOT checked. Your code ran fine after changing that. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

**2**.Another solution is to use layers.Raycasting but ignoring the `Player` layer.Before you do that, make sure to create a layer called `Ground` and put your ground GameObject to the `Ground` layer then create another layer called Player and put your player in the `Player` layer. We can now use `bitwise` operator to **exclude** `Player` layer from the raycast.

[image]

Now, lets assume that Player layer number is `9`. The code below should fix your problem.

```
public int playerLayer = 9;
int layerMask = ~(1 << playerLayer); //Exclude layer 9
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayOrigin, Vector2.down, 0.1f, layerMask);
```

**That's it**. Both of these were able to solve your problem.

*For other people reading, below are other ways to easily detect when `Player` is touching the floor without using `Physics2D.Raycast` or doing all those things above.*

Simply attach to the `Player`.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    Collider2D playerCollider;
    bool grounded;

    void Start()
    {
        playerCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }

    public bool IsGrounded()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(playerCollider.transform.position, 1, groundLayer);
        return grounded;
    }
}
```

Or you can use `IsTouchingLayers`.

```
public bool IsGrounded()
{
    grounded = grounded = playerCollider.IsTouchingLayers(groundLayer.value);
    return grounded;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I was using IsTouchingLayers() before to try the raycast approach, since IsTouchingLayers() returns true even if the player is jumping against a wall (instead the detection should happen only toward the bottom of the player sprite, that's why I opted for a raycast)... I didn't try the OverlapCircle() but I fear that it could have the same undesired effect :P Anyway I don't understand why by default the raycast should start in the collider itself... what's the point of drawing a ray inside an object?!

Comment: I believe you can also use `Physics2D.RaycastAll`. The result is ordered in distance (though I don't know if ascending or descending).

Comment: @GunnarB. Yes you can. I only posted few  solutions with less memory allocation. I mean, why allocate memory with array while you can just do raycast and exclude some layers? The more GameObject in the scene, the more memory `Physics2D.RaycastAll` allocate.

Comment: @daveoncode **"I didn't try the OverlapCircle() but I fear that it could have the same undesired effect"**  This is programming. Without trying and failing, you wont know what works or not. You always experiment as a programmer. **"I don't understand why by default the raycast should start in the collider itself"** That's Unity for you. I don't know their reason for that but it was done on purpose. That's why they put option to disable it.  You got it working, right? Which method did you use?

Comment: You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

The thing makes problem is its ray hits its own collider. At least i have met with this problem many times. You can pass this problem making group itself or related gameobjects then you can code it as below. This ~ tilde is layer inverter in the code.

```
public void CheckRay(float rayLength)
{
    Ray directionRay = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * rayLength, Color.cyan, 5f);
    int xRayedTriggers = Physics.RaycastNonAlloc(directionRay, _hits, rayLength, ~ignoredItselfLayerMask);

    Debug.LogAssertion("Layer Total > " + xRayedTriggers);

    for (int i = 0; i < xRayedTriggers; i++)
    {
        Debug.LogAssertion(_hits[i].transform.tag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone encounters this problem this might help. OverlapBox and Raycast hits if the gameobject intersects its own collider. ^^

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Vector2.down vector does not present the object space's down vector all the time. You can use `-transform.up`.

Also, if it is acceptable you can add some padding to start point of the ray, like `rayOrigin.y += 0.0001f;`.

Comment: transform.down?! are you sure? it seems it does not exist :/

Comment: He meant Vector2.down

Comment: it seems that `transform.up` exists, so I tried with `-transform.up`, but the problem is the same :(

Comment: oops. my bad. do you want another solution to use? I've got another working solution. No raycast. I tested your code and I am having the-same  problem as you

Comment: I want to understand how raycast works and use it, I'm not a copy/paste programmer looking for a piece of code! -__-

Comment: What about the padding? You see, if the origin of the ray is inside of the collider itself, it is understandable why it is returning player as a hit result.