# Unity Raycast always returning true

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have a character in Unity that I'm using a raycast to have him jump. But even when the raycast doesn't hit the ground (I can see the ray with the debug output) the player still can jump. Any ideas why the ray is always thinks it is colliding? Could the ray be hitting my character collider, causing it to be true? Ive been search online for hours and nothing I find is fixing the situation. Here is my code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Ray ray = new Ray();
    RaycastHit hit;
    ray.origin = transform.position;
    ray.direction = Vector3.down;
    bool output = Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.red);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && output)
    {
        r.AddForce(Vector3.up * 1f, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried moving the `ray.origin` to be outside of your character collider?

Comment: Yes, so when I put the ray lower (below the character and the ground) there is no jumping, which makes sense. But It i just put it below the character  (still above the ground, as close to level with characters feet as possible), it never detects the ground and constantly allows jumping

Comment: also when I put the ray above my character, like far a above, it still allows for jumping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could the ray be hitting my character collider?

Yes, that is possible.

This is actually problem that can easily be solve with `Debug.Log`.

Put `Debug.Log("Ray Hit: " + hit.transform.name);` inside the `if` statement and it will show what Object is blocking the `Raycast`.

If this is indeed the problem, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38193001/3785314) post describes many ways to fix it. That answer and code changes a little bit because this question is about 3D not 2D. Just use layer. Put your player in Layer 9 then the problem should go away.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    int playerLayer = 9;

    //Exclude layer 9
    int layerMask = ~(1 << playerLayer); 


    Ray ray = new Ray();
    RaycastHit hit;
    ray.origin = transform.position;
    ray.direction = Vector3.down;
    bool output = Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f, layerMask);



    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction, Color.red);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && output)
    {
        r.AddForce(Vector3.up * 1f, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        Debug.Log("Ray Hit: " + hit.transform.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! from the output of the debug log, it was hitting the character collider! But the layer fix you mentioned doesn't seem to be working, is there anything more than just replacing my code withe the above code? Do I have to "put" my character into layer 9 some other way?

Comment: Create a layer in Layer 9 then name it "Player". Select your character and the the Layer to "Player". When I say layer, I don't mean *Tag*. Please  watch [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/layers) youtube video about creating and changing layers. When that is done and not working, please increase `100f` to about `800f` and see what happens.

Comment: You can also replace the `100` with `Mathf.Infinity`