# Unity2D preventing character from multi-jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character can jump as much as you press ( W or space) I've read that you can prevent it with Raycast, but I don't understand how to do so. This is my character's code(this is a platformer game) :

```
private Rigidbody2D myRigidBody2D;
void Start () {

    myRigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        myRigidBody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've read that you can prevent it with Raycast

Yes, you can but you will likely run into [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191659/unity-physics2d-raycast-always-returns-the-invoker-as-hit/38193001#38193001) which can still be fixed.

The best way to do this is to use a boolean variable to check if the character is touching the ground or not. You can set this variable to `true` or `false` in the `OnCollisionEnter2D` and `OnCollisionExit2D` functions.

[Create a tag](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/tags) called "`Ground`". Change all your ground Gameobjects to this tag then the example below should prevent multiple jumping.

```
bool isGrounded = true;

private float jumpForce = 2f;
private Rigidbody2D myRigidBody2D;

void Start()
{

    myRigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        myRigidBody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```