# Unity Raycast2D only shoots like 1 unit

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have a 2D character with a gun, and I want to instantiate an explosion where his shot collides with something else.

I thought the best way to do this would be Raycast2D in javascript.

```
var hit: RaycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right);
if (hit.collider != null){
    boomClone2 = Instantiate(boom, new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, transform.position.z - 1), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Now the problem is I fire, and the explosion instantiates always like one unit in front of my character, even if there is nothing there.  I have no idea why.

Comment: *"nstantiates always like one unit in front of my character, even if there is nothing there."* Can you explain this more? Maybe a screenshot of what you are talking about...

Comment: It looks like this:   CHARACTER___________    <EXPLO>_______________                             ENEMY

Comment: It doesn't instantiate on the enemy, it only instantiates a few units in front of the character

Comment: Have you tried changing the vector3 in the Instantiate method call? Which is the transform where you are calling this? (The character, the enemy or the explosion?)

Comment: have you tried simply printing out the name of the object you're colliding with? That would go along way towards helping you debug this. From there you can add conditions verifying that the prefab only instantiates when it hits things that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change raycast's origin. Or you can create new layer for player. and exclude that layer when  raycast.

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (transform.position, Vector2.right, ~(LayerMask.GetMask ("player")));
```

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem is that you are **not** even checking which Object the raycast hit before instantiating anything. This is wrong. The raycast can hit anything in front of it. Anything with a Collider 2D. It can even hit the character itself.

Create an "Enemy" tag Put your enemies in that tag. When the raycast is not `null`, make sure that the Enemy is actually hit before instantiating anything.

```
if (hit.collider != null)
{
    if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        boomClone2 = Instantiate(boom, new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, transform.position.z - 1), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

---

Like I said, the raycast can even hit itself especially when 2D raycast is done. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191659/unity-physics2d-raycast-always-returns-the-invoker-as-hit/38193001#38193001) post for how to fix this issue too if that's the problem.